# Unable to locate a class or view for component

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-8

laravel 8.28, Devilbox.

- i've created a new component named forms under another folder:

`php artisan make:component new folder/form`

- added some html to resources/views/components/newfolder/form.blade.php
- created a new view under resources/views/newfolder/create.blade.php
- inside create.blade.php added:

`<x-newfolder-form></x-newfolder-form>`

- when i load the the view i get:

`InvalidArgumentException Unable to locate a class or view for component [newfolder-form].`

i've tried capitalized component name and doesn't work, can you please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You're referencing the component incorrectly, it should be:

`<x-newfolder.form></x-newfolder.form>`

Components in subfolders are referenced using a period (dot) `.` and not a hyphen `-`.